# Error: C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe failed with return code: 4294967295

Tags: azure, web-applications, deployment, azure-devops, msdeploy

I could use some assistance. I have a release that keeps failing in Azure, specifically on the Azure App Service Deploy step.

(Note: I am a web designer and currently don't have access to someone who can assist me, all of this was setup by someone no longer with the company.)

I have tried restarting the app service and in the app settings i have MSDEPLOY_RENAME_LOCKED_FILES = 1

[screenshot of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdHI9.jpg)

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here are several approaches you could try:

Approach 1:

You can use Azure PowerShell Task to stop-start App Service and deploy to slots and swap the slot with production.

```
Stop-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName "RG_Name" -Name "App_Service_Name"
Start-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName "RG_Name" -Name "App_Service_Name"
```

Approach 2:

You could upgrad to 4.* task version and use `RunFromPackage` to deploy. Please note that this makes the package folder read only. For more information go through this [article](https://aka.ms/azurermwebdeployreadme).

Approach 3:

You can use the curl command provided [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-from-a-zip-file) to use the `Zip Deploy` command.
You can also pull from the repo and upload the task to your account.

For more details, you could refer to this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/5259#issuecomment-407804662).

Comment: I forgot to mention, this is for a QA environment, not my production environment, thou the releases are setup so they move from one spot to another. Im not sure what deploying to slots means?